# Accessing Companies House API using R: Status: 400

Tags: r, httr

I am trying to get some information from companies house programmatically in R
I tried to use the [package](https://github.com/MatthewSmith430/CompaniesHouse) `CompaniesHouse` but am getting a failed attempt.
I have my key which i got from their dev pages.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(keyring)
library(CompaniesHouse)

# Get the companies house keys
mkey <- key_get("company_house","companies_login")

# Taken from the github repo
CompanySearchList <- search_company(company = "unilever", mkey = mkey)

# No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
# Error in data.frame(id.search.term = company, company.name = DFfirmNAMES,  : 
# arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
```

I dug into the function and can see I am getting a status 400 error.

```r
# A slimmed down version of the code in the function

search_company <- function (company, mkey) 
{
  firmNAME <- gsub(" ", "+", company)
  firmNAME <- gsub("&", "%26", firmNAME)
  FIRMurl <- paste0("https://api.company-information.service.gov.uk/search/companies?q=",firmNAME)
  firmTEST <- httr::GET(FIRMurl, httr::authenticate(mkey, ""))
  firmTEXT <- httr::content(firmTEST, as = "text")
}
```

It returns the following on the line `firmTEST <- httr::GET(FIRMurl, httr::authenticate(mkey, ""))`

```
Response [https://api.company-information.service.gov.uk/search/companies?q=unilever]
  Date: 2023-03-28 07:20
  Status: 400
  Content-Type: application/json
  Size: 60 B
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Check the documentation here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/api-packages.html - particularly the sections "passing parameters" and "Authentication" - the syntax in your comment doesn't quite line up with these - possibly it was written for an earlier version of the package?

Comment: The authentication and format for queries to companies house can be checked here: https://developer-specs.company-information.service.gov.uk/companies-house-public-data-api/reference

Comment: Having made an account at companies house and played around with it, I can either get a `Status: 401` (not authorised) or `Status: 400` (bad request) - I can't seem to easily get it to return what is needed.  I'll report back if I have any success.